# Git branch not highlight in VS Code

Tags: git, visual-studio-code

I can check it in the bottom left and with `git status`, i know.
What bugs me is that I cannot see the git branch highlighted in green with a * in the console anymore as seen in this photo:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/1U3ok.jpg

I find this really odd as I haven't changed any settings in VSCode at all and I can move around checking out branches just fine. I restarted it and it's the same. Does anyone know why this might be happening and how to fix it? I know it's silly but I really found it useful when switching between multiple instances of VSCode with multiple branches open at once to see which one I was in more easily.

Comment: What happens in your terminal is not scope of VS code, this should be a shell setting. What shell are you using?

Comment: zsh, but it's working again so im unconcerned though I would have liked to understand why it stopped for a day. this was within vscode, so idk if its the same as my terminal app